# How can I calculate the number of solar panels required to power a specific load?

Tags: electrical, solar-panels

I recently purchased a home in Maricopa AZ. With that said, I'd like for it to be most efficient. It has a forced air system for heat and cooling. I don't know the size of the cooling unit. How does one figure out the number of panels needed to properly supply enough current to operate devices properly.

Comment: This would take a LOT to answer. I would try to find a book on the subject, and there are surely many such books on the market.

Comment: Just because it is a hard question doesn't mean it is bad - but we need a lot more info in the question.

Answer (score 1):

1. Calculate the required load for your house.  Call that L
2. Identify the rated power one panel generates.  Call that P
3. L/P = Q - quantity of panels needed.

Comment: You may need to add a few panels, even in AZ you will not get full power 24/7/365.

Comment: Rated power on a lot of newer solar panels are now rated at an average WattHour per day and have a scale for regions, not just max Wattage. But this does still only calculate the bare minimum and doesn't take loss in line voltage, storage capabilities, nor inverting.